# Fold left and fold right

Tags: scala, functional-programming, purely-functional

I am trying to learn how to use fold left and fold right. This is my first time learning functional programming. I am having trouble understanding when to use fold left and when to use fold right. It seems to me that a lot of the time the two functions are interchangeable. For example (in Scala)the two functions:

```
val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val sum1 = nums.foldLeft(0) { (total, n) =>
  total + n
}
val sum2 = nums.foldRight(0) {(total, n) =>
  total + n
}
```

both yield the same result. Why and when would I choose one or the other?

Comment: Now try to subtract or do division and see if you're still getting the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

foldleft and foldright differ in the way the function is nested.

```
foldleft: (((...) + a) + a) + a
foldright: a + (a + (a + (...)))
```

Since the function you are using is addition, both of them give the same result. Try using subtraction.

Moreover, the motivation to use fold(left/right) is not the result - in most of the cases, both yield the same result. It depends on which you you want your function to be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the operator you are using is **associated & commutative operator** means `a + b = b + a` that's why `leftFold` and `rightFold` worked equivalent but it's not the equivalent in general as you can visualised by below examples where operator(+) is **not associative & commutative** operation i.e in case of string concatenation '+' operator is not associative & commutative means `'a' + 'b' != 'b' + 'a'`

```
val listString = List("a", "b", "c") // : List[String] = List(a,b,c)
val leftFoldValue = listString.foldLeft("z")((el, acc) => el + acc) // : String = zabc
val rightFoldValue = listString.foldRight("z")((el, acc) => el + acc) // : abcz
```

OR in shorthand ways

```
val leftFoldValue = listString.foldLeft("z")(_ + _) // : String = zabc
val rightFoldValue = listString.foldRight("z")(_ + _) // : String = abcz
```

Explanation:

`leftFold` is worked as `( ( ('z' + 'a') + 'b') + 'c') = ( ('za' + 'b') + 'c') = ('zab' + 'c') = 'zabc'`

and `rightFold` as `('a' + ('b' + ('c' + 'z'))) = ('a' + ('b' + 'cz')) = ('a' + 'bcz') = 'abcz'`

So in short for **operators that are associative and commutative, foldLeft and
foldRight are equivalent** (even though there may be a difference in
efficiency).
But sometimes, only one of the two operators is appropriate.